# How to inject a method to all old style classes dynamically in Python 2

Tags: python, metaprogramming, inject

In my codes, I want to inject a method to all old style classes in Python 2, such as ConfigParser.ConfigParser.

For the new style class, I can just inject a mehtod called 'pp' to the class called 'object', then all classes which entend from it could have 'pp'.

But when I try to do the same thing into all old style classes in Python 2, I cannot find a way to do it.

I've tried the below codes:

```
class OldStyle:
    pass
print type(OldStyle) # <type 'classobj'>
old_one = OldStyle()
print dir(old_one) # ['__doc__', '__module__']
```

And I want to add method to ALL old style classes, not just only for one or two.

Does anyone can help me.

Comment: Python is not Ruby. Don't try and do this.

Comment: Yes, Daniel, you maybe right.

Comment: Have you tried adding a function to the class. That should just work. `inst = OldClass(); OldClass.f = lambda self: self; assert inst.f() == inst`

Comment: Hi Dunes, what I want to do is add one method to all old style class, not just for one.

Comment: You can't do that with new style classes either... `classobj` and `object` are both builtin types and do not have a dynamic namespace.

Comment: The most you could do is inject a method to ConfigParser instances and all its subclasses instances, but not to every single object in the program.

Comment: Dunes, thanks for your suggestion. But I want to inject to every old style class, not only for ConfigParser and its subclasses.